# How to infer literal type in Flow?

Tags: flowtype

Is there a way to infer literal type with Flow in a generic way without explicit type casting?

Here's an example that should explain what I want to do. This code will not work with Flow because there's not `$Literal` utility type.

```
// explicit type casting to literal type
const a: 'flow' = 'flow

// inferring literal type

type Primitive = null | void | boolean | number | string

function literal <T: Primitive>(value: T): $Literal<T> {
  return value
}

// cast type with generic function - type is inferred to 'flow' string literal
const a = literal('flow')
```

Comment: I was going to refer you to the Flow docs - [Literal Types](https://flow.org/en/docs/types/literals/).  But I suspect that your `literal` function must have a side effect and your trying to avoid duplication of the literal.  Otherwise, can you expand the example?

Comment: I want to assign a variable with inferred literal type. For example if I assign variable to a string value, the inferred type will be _string_ not _string_ literal. I'm trying to figure if this is somehow possible with Flow.

Comment: Your example shows you passing a literal to a function, and you are hoping for the return value to be a literal type in flow.  You're not explaining what purpose the `literal()` method has, because it seems to be redundant.  If the parameter was a variable, you'd have a point, but your example is a literal.

Comment: Yes, I'm passing a JavaScript string literal but Flow is inferring this to _string_ type. You have to explicitly cast to string literal type (see first statement in example).

My question was how can be we infer literal type without explicit annotation (see last statement is the example).

Comment: It looks like it's not possible to infer literal types. Here's the answer. https://github.com/facebook/flow/issues/2639